# How to handle FormData in Miragejs?

Tags: fetch, miragejs

Miragejs handles json out-of-the-box but seems to be unable to handle FormData. When I post FormData and log the received `request` in mirage endpoint, `request.requestBody` is empty.

Simplified code examples:

- POSTing FormData:

```js
const testFile = new File(['hello'], 'hello.png', { type: 'image/png' });
const formData = new FormData('file', testFile);
fetch('https://localhost:3000/api/endpoint', {method: 'POST', body: formData});
// ...
```

- receiving POST in mirage mock server:

```js
this.post('/endpoint', (schema, request) => {
  console.log('request:', request);
  // request.requestBody is an empty string!  
});
```

Possibly a related issue: https://github.com/miragejs/ember-cli-mirage/issues/74

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to cast the `request.requestBody` to `FormData` and then parse the file.

Shortening the excellent solution described in [How to handle uploading and parsing files in your frontend app tests](https://medium.com/qonto-way/how-to-handle-uploading-and-parsing-files-in-your-frontend-app-tests-19bee8e7a61f):

```js
this.post('/endpoint', (schema, request) => {
  const readFile = async (file: File): Promise<string> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onerror = () => reject(new Error('There was an error reading the file!'));
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      reader.readAsText(file);
    });
  const formData: FormData = request.requestBody as unknown as FormData;
  const uploadFile: File = formData.get('file') as File;
  const fileContents: string = await readFile(uploadFile);
  console.log('Uploaded file contents:', fileContents);
});
```